# Struggling to hide a row based on the value of a specific column (should be easy in theory...)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

What should be a very simple problem has had me stuck for a couple of days and as per usual, although there are plenty of similar questions, there is no exact match (possibly because I'm using  elements to create a table, rather than ).

In short, I have a button, which when clicked sends a market id to the function below (this works correctly for the avoidance of doubt).

The idea is that, the function then hides all the table rows that do not have this market id in the Market Id column. Simple enough!

However, for some reason, I don't seem to be able to do this, as I'm constantly getting type errors.

I have tried finding the child nodes and attempting to derive the parent and also the reverse, but so far no luck.

I don't have to use this approach, so long as I can hide all rows that don't contain the market id when its passed to the function, that would be fine.

However, I'm out of ideas, so any help is appreciated!

I've tried multiple approaches (e.g. parentNode, childNode, children etc.), however I always get a similar error to the one below.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="divTable blueTable" id="bluetable">
<div class="divTableHeading" id="blue_table_head">
<div class="divTableRow" id="header_row">
<div class="divTableHead">Selection Name</div>
<div class="divTableHead">Selection ID</div>
<div class="divTableHead">Market ID</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableBody" id="blue_table_body">
<div class="divTableRow" id="blue_table_row_0">
<div class="divTableCell"><div>Selection A</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>1136035</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div class="1.15">1.15</div></div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow" id="blue_table_row_1">
<div class="divTableCell"><div>Selection B</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>11148977</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div class="1.15">1.15</div></div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow" id="blue_table_row_2">
<div class="divTableCell"><div>Selection C</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>4519440</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div class="1.15">1.15</div></div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow" id="blue_table_row_3">
<div class="divTableCell"><div>Selection D</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>10974022</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div class="1.16">1.16</div></div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow" id="blue_table_row_4">
<div class="divTableCell"><div>Selection E</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div>1136034</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div class="1.17">1.17</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript function:

```
function btn_click($button_id) {

var list = document.getElementsByClassName("divTableRow");

    for (a = 2; a < list.length; a++) {

        var b = list[a];
        var c = b.getElementsByClassName($button_id);
        var d = c.parentNode.nodeName;
        console.log(d);

    }

}
```

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
```

However, if I just look at the log for 'c' (i.e. console.log(c)) I can see the id from $button_id is correctly returning the related class.

Therefore I need to somehow work out an alternative way of determining which row's are the correct ones to hide, but am a bit stuck.

Comment: getElementsByClassName() returns a set of items you have to loop through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Try with getElementById or c[0].parentNode.nodeName;

Comment: Trying that approach, I still get the error as follows:  
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined`
I have added in a loop, shown in the thread below (I won't re-post to avoid confusion), which returns the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Funk Doc commented, the issue is that you are using

```
var c = b.getElementsByClassName($button_id);
```

Which returns **an array of elements**.

The fix: if you want to use all of these elements, loop through them, like:

```
var c = b.getElementsByClassName($button_id);
for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  var e = c[i].parentNode.parentNode.id;
  //whatever you want to do next
}
```

Interestingly though, using a foreach loop (like `for(var i in c) {...}`) instead does cause a `TypeError`.

But if you expect to be only one element there, use

```
var c = b.getElementsByClassName($button_id)[0];
```

Comment: I did initially try a second loop, but took it out, ha! I've added it back in as you suggested, but I still get the error. Here is the code:  
  
`function btn_click($button_id) {

var list = document.getElementsByClassName("divTableRow");
 
 for (a = 2; a < list.length; a++) {

  var b = list[a];
  var c = b.getElementsByClassName($button_id);

   for (d in c) {
 
   var e = c[d].parentNode.nodeName;
   console.log(e);

   }
 

 }

}`
  
Here is the error:  
  
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined`

Comment: In a loop of the form `for(d in c)`, d is an element of c, not an index!

Comment: So inside the loop, instead of using `var e = c[d].parentNode.nodeName;`, you should do `var e = d.parentNode.nodeName;`

Comment: unfortunately that returns exactly the same error :-(

Comment: Hmm.. try console logging d inside the loop. What do you get?

Comment: Interesting....so console.log(d) inside the loop, returns multiple:  `0
(index):451 length
(index):451 item
(index):451 namedItem`

Comment: I just tested something similar now, and it seems to work when you use regular for loop with indices (like `for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {`) and using `var e = c[i].parentNode.nodeName`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that does not return an error as you stated, however the log is just DIV, which is the direct parent. I actually need a level up from that, i.e. the id of the divTableRow, so I think I need to add another step in somehow!

Is there an easy way of skipping up one more level, or will I need to reformat my table to include an id for the direct parent Divs (which presumably is the divTableCell and then perform another loop to iterate through that)?

Comment: You could call `c[i].parentNode.parentNode.id` to get the id of the parent's parent. If it is the id that you want, then you don't want `nodeName` property, but `id`. Answer updated.

Comment: Ah perfect, yes, that is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated, I will mark this as answered. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function btn_click($button_id) {
    // get all table rows
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.divTableBody .divTableRow');

    // loop through the rows
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // check if row has no descendant div with class = $button_id
        if (!rows[i].querySelector('div[class="divTableCell"] div[class="' + $button_id + '"]')) {
            // hide row if condition is true
            rows[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does indeed work, although I'll need to add another step as although for the first click it returns the rows as expected I didn't mention that it needs to work for an infinite number of button clicks. This doesn't return any rows for subsequent button clicks, so I'll need to tweak it slightly.

Comment: I see. I thought you wanted to hide all table rows that don't have $button_id. Anyways, I hope this will be  helpful for you. I always find it easier to use the querySelector to find nested elements because it accepts any valid CSS selector as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, sorry my fault, my initial description wasn't very clear on that part, but not to worry, your answer is still helpful as I should be able to play around with it to get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is of use to anyone else, here is the final code:

```
function btn_click($button_id) {

var list = document.getElementsByClassName("divTableRow");

    for (a = 2; a < list.length; a++) {

        var b = list[a];
        b.style.display = 'none';
        var c = b.getElementsByClassName($button_id);

            for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) { 
                var e = c[i].parentNode.parentNode.id;
                document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'table-row';

            }

    }

}
```